# Using map with two lists rather than one. Can you nest?

Tags: haskell, mapping

I need to run a function that takes two arguments several times.  I have two lists containing these arguments and I'd like to be able to use `map` or something similar to call the function with the corresponding args.

The function I want to call has this type:

```
runParseTest :: String -> String -> IO()
```

The lists are created like this:

```
-- Get list of files in libraries directory
files <- getDirectoryContents "tests/libraries"
-- Filter out ".." and "." and add path
let names = filter (\x -> head x /= '.') files
let libs = ["tests/libraries/" ++ f | f <- names]
```

So lets say that `names` contains `["test1.js", "test2.js", "test3.js"]` and `libs` contains `["tests/libraries/test1.js", "tests/libraries/test2.js", "tests/libraries/test3.js"]`

I want to call them like this:

```
runParseTest "test1.js" "tests/libraries/test1.js"
runParseTest "test2.js" "tests/libraries/test2.js"
runParseTest "test3.js" "tests/libraries/test3.js"
```

I know I could create a helper function that does this fairly easily, but out of interest, is it possible to do in one line using `map`?

This is what I have so far, but obviously the first argument is always "test":

```
mapM_ (runParseTest "test") libs
```

I apologise if this is unclear.  I can provide more info if necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So lets say that names contains `["test1.js", "test2.js", "test3.js"]`
> and libs contains `["tests/libraries/test1.js", "tests/libraries/test2.js", "tests/libraries/test3.js"]`
>
> I want to call them like this:
>
> `runParseTest "test1.js" "tests/libraries/test1.js"`
> `runParseTest "test2.js" "tests/libraries/test2.js"`
>  `runParseTest "test3.js" "tests/libraries/test3.js"`

It's possible to do that with `zip`:

```
map (\(a,b) -> runParseTest a b) $ zip names libs
```

Or maybe `uncurry runParseTest`:

```
 map (uncurry runParseTest) $ zip names libs
```

Or with `zipWith`:

```
 zipWith runParseTest names libs
```

And like [Ozgur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448701/570689) said, there are some analogues for monads:

```
> :t zipWithM
zipWithM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m [c]
> :t zipWithM_
zipWithM_ :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m ()
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I've actually written a new function called `map2M_` which I will post but this is the "correct" way of doing it I'm sure.

Answer (score 20):

This is a great time to use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)!  Hoogle is a search engine for searching Haskell *types*.  For instance, a Hoogle query for [`(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20%5ba%5d%20-%3E%20%5bb%5d) pulls up [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap).  Here, you have a function of type `String -> String -> IO ()`; you want a function of type `(String -> String -> IO ()) -> [String] -> [String] -> IO ()`.  Hoogle can often generalize by itself, but it's having trouble here, so let's help it out: You just want `(a -> a -> IO ()) -> [a] -> [a] -> IO ()` for any `a`.  If you [Hoogle for that type signature](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+IO+%28%29%29+-%3E+%5ba%5d+-%3E+%5ba%5d+-%3E+IO+%28%29), the first result is [`zipWithM_ :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3azipWithM_) in the [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html) module, which does exactly what you want.  This is part of a family of functions, with varying degrees of generality:

- [`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3azip), which pairs up two lists, truncating the shorter one.
- [`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith), which runs a supplied function on elements from each of the two lists; `zip = zipWith (,)`.
- [`zipWithM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m [c]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3azipWithM), which is like `zipWith` inside a monad; `zipWithM f xs ys = sequence $ zipWith f xs ys`.
- [`zipWithM_ :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3azipWithM_), which is like `zipWithM` but discards its result; `zipWithM_ f xs ys = zipWithM f xs ys >> return () = sequence_ $ zipWith f xs ys`.
- [`zip3 :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3azip3), whose functionality I'm sure you can figure out :-)
- [`zipWith3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith3), which is like `zipWith` on *three* lists; `zipWith3 = zip (,,)`.
- A family of `zipN` and `zipWithN` functions [in Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html), going up through `zip7`/`zipWith7`.  (Arguably, this starts with [`id :: [a] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aid) as `zip1` and [`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap) as `zipWith1`, which is where your question comes from.)
- And, in greatest generality, the [`ZipList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aZipList) applicative functor.  Given some lists `xs1`…`xsN`, then `runZipList $ f <$> ZipList xs1 <*> ZipList xs2 <*> ... <*> ZipList xsN = runZipList $ liftAN f (ZipList xs1) ... (ZipList xsN`) behaves just like `zipWithN f xs1 ... xsN`.

So, in your specific use case, we're going to have—with a few extra changes—the following:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

...

-- I got rid of `head` because it's a partial function, and I prefer `map` to
-- list comprehensions for simple things    
do files <- getDirectoryContents "tests/libraries"
   let names = filter (not . ("." `isPrefixOf`)) files
       libs  = map ("tests/libraries/" ++) names
   zipWithM_ runParseTest names libs
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [zipWithM_](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3azipWithM_).

You say you could write a helper function which does this. Which means you know the type of the function you are looking for. In such cases you can use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle).

(Try: Monad m => [a] -> [b] -> m ())

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for answers I created a solution of my own with a new function called `map2M_` based on the source code for `map` and `mapM_`:

```
map2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
map2 _ [] _          = []
map2 _ _ []          = []
map2 f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : map2 f as bs

map2M_ :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m ()
map2M_ f as bs =  sequence_ (map2 f as bs)
```