# How to apply a function on each element in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, happstack

I have a list of tuples here, and I want to apply function `dir..`on the first element in each tuple. How can I do that? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
[ ("grid", gridResponse),
("graph", graphResponse),
("image", graphImageResponse),
("timetable-image", timetableImageResponse x),
("graph-fb",toResponse ""),
("post-fb",toResponse ""),
("test", getEmail),
("test-post", postToFacebook),
("post", postResponse),
("draw", drawResponse),                  
("about", aboutResponse),
("privacy" ,privacyResponse),
("static", serveDirectory),
("course", retrieveCourse),
("all-courses", allCourses),
("graphs", queryGraphs),
("course-info", courseInfo),
("depts", deptList),
("timesearch",searchResponse),
("calendar",calendarResponse),
("get-json-data",getGraphJSON),
("loading",loadingResponse),
("save-json", saveGraphJSON)］
```

Comment: Do you know about `map` ?

Comment: `map (dir . fst) data`

Comment: Do you want to pull out the data, apply it, and return that list, or apply in place, returning the new value in the fst position, the original value in the snd position?  I'd recommend map for the former, lenses for the latter.

Comment: Thanks to everyone here! `map` is very useful!

Comment: As an exercise, you should solve this using both `map` and explicit recursion with pattern matching. `f [] = ... ; f ((x,y):rest) = ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) is defined as:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This means it is a function that takes a function that goes from type a to type b and a list of type a, and then returns a list of type b. As pointed out by @pdexter and @karakfa in the comments, this is exactly what you need.

```
map f list
```

So what f do you need? Well, your list is a list of tuples and you want to apply a function to the first element to each tuple, so (exactly as @karakfa pointed out) all you need is

```
map (dir . fst) list
```

This composes the function fst with your custom dir function to give you a new function that will take the first element of a tuple and do whatever your dir function does to it. Then map applies that over the entire list.

Comment: a further question here: what if I want to apply map on a function that takes in two variables? For example,  I have a function called `doubleUs` here, and `doubleUs = x*2 + y*2`. And x is from list [1,2,3], y is from list [2,3,4]. How can I achieve that?

Comment: That's been answered a few times on this site before. Take a look at [this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448570/using-map-with-two-lists-rather-than-one-can-you-nest) as an example.